# Where to find Log4j debug information

Tags: java, log4j

Current project is with Log4J 1.2.17

Looks like Log4j can also output debug information for itself by

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

My question is where to find those debug information, where is the output? I check server log and application log but didn't see anything?

Answer (score 0):

You have specify one of the appenders:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

It can be FileAppender where the output will be to a file you specify in conf file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Or ConsoleAppender where it will be printed to console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Furthermore make sure the application does log DEBUG statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry my question is not about log4J application log, but about how to debug log4j and find the debug log while debugging Log4J

Comment: Those messages should appear in the STDOUT. Run your application from the console and you can see the messages there.

Comment: Thanks again, but also hope to find a way to make the debug info output somewhere, like another JVM parm to guide where those information should output to